# scanning the web page and find out any illegal word wraps

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation

I need to automate a scenario where the script has to scan the whole and verify if there are any legal and illegal word wraps found,and highlight the same. The legal and illegal word wraps will supplied as input data excel along with the web url to check.

can we achieve this with any test automation tool? like selenium(preferred)?

Comment: Just out of curiousity, what constitutes a "legal" or an "illegal" word wrap?

Comment: Have you tried [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/)? Will it help in your case?

Comment: If you want to test your website against few illegal or legal key words then you can also use JMeter. With some regular expression you can test the occurrence of those keywords

Comment: @ChrisForrence any word which wrapped in web page display at wrong position is illegal.. ex: for iphone 7s, the display should be complete iphone 7s on a single line or iphone one line and below it 7S which is called legal and if iphone 7 is displayed in one line and S is displayed below it - then it is illegal.. we need to find these kind of occurrences and highlight.

Comment: @a_a: not sure of Jsoup.. can you please look at my above comment and let me know if jsoup can be of help. so that I can try it out.. thanks

Comment: This distortion of word, like you mentioned in your comment, is because of screen resolution change or bad UI design?

Comment: might be due to screen resolution i guess.. but reasons may vary since this involves multiple websits

Answer (score 0):

Well,

I'm not sure which word is legal or illegal on your approach, but you may create a dictionary with these legal/illegal words and check if they are present on the page?

Just get the entire page source and perform a scan using the your own dictionary

```
String pageSource = driver.getPageSource()
```

Does it make sense?

Comment: i dont think.. the question is more of checking the display - while page source will get the whole page text.. Please refer to comments i added above..

Comment: @user2637464, got it, trying to think on something to help you

Comment: why not to use Sikuli (http://sikulix.com/) as an "image repository"? So you can check if the iPhone 7 image is present on screen with Sikuli and with Selenium you can check if the label is iPhone 7 too.

Comment: yes thought of the Sikuli option but considering the below limitation looking for any other solution: 1. there will be numerous legal and illegal keywords going forward which would be tough to capture and test. 2. As well came to know that even if there is slight variation in pixels from actual to expected, the test fails.. and focus here is distortion due to resolution or web page constraints. Hence thought may not be much helpful. Correct me if I am wrong?